# Expressing a function in terms of $z^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

One of the exercises in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis text is expressing the sum $$S(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{z^3-n^3} $$
in closed form.

I believe that $$ S(z)=\frac{\pi}{3z^2} \left(  \cot \pi z+e^\frac{2 \pi i}{3} \cot \pi e^\frac{2\pi i}{3} z+e^\frac{4 \pi i}{3} \cot \pi e^\frac{4 \pi i}{3} \right).$$

What bothers me, is that the series representation shows that $S(z)$ is a function of $z^3$ alone, while this is not so obvious in the trigonometric expression (I know it is true nonetheless). Is there a way to modify the last expression for $S(z)$, so that it will depend on $z^3$ as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to write $$S(z)=\frac{\pi }{z^3}\frac{f(z)+f(e^{2\pi i/3}z)+ f(e^{4\pi i/3}z)}{3}, \quad \text{where } \ f(z)=z\cot \pi z\tag1$$
The second factor is not explicitly written in terms of $z$, but it's clear that its expansion in powers of $z$ will only contain the terms $z^{3k}$: the others cancel out. Namely, 
$$S(z)=\frac{\pi }{z^3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{3k} z^{3k}, \quad \text{where } \ \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k =z\cot \pi z \tag2$$

I don't think it's possible to have at the same time a trigonometric form as in (1) and explicit dependence on $z^3$ as in (2). Compare with the following simpler example: $e^z+e^{-z}$ is a function of $z^2$ only, but can't be explicitly written that way without abandoning the exponential function notation.